# how to snap two line vertex in two different layers used in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, snapping

[image]

I want to snap between two poly-lines from 2 different layers (Layer1 in Brown and Layer 2(postGIS layer) in Pink color- ), but my snap option don't work. I have changed the tolerance to different levels but still not getting the results.

[image]

I don't get the magenta + sign to appear near vertices for snapping as many say it online.

1. Which tool used for snapping? I know only the "Node tool" which is not working .
2. I have set both layers editable (toggle editing set: ON)
3. Is there any better plugins there(I have tried many available ones.)?

Please give me suggestions since I am a beginner in QGIS.

Comment: I always use pixel as snapping units. If map units are degree, you will rarely get snapping with 6 map units.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to make it more readable, but still I think it might need some work. Can you clarify what you mean by points 1 & 2?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I have modified the question. Please see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your first picture no 'Enable Snapping' options... Make settings as shown below:

[image]