# Two inner polygons touching and covered by two different outer polygons

Tags: qgis, topology

[image: topology]

I need to create a topology where 1 and 2 touch but don't overlap, a and b touch but don't overlap, and 1 covers a and 2 covers b.  Is it possible to achieve this?  I've tried various snapping options, but they all seem to result in one of the inner polygons overlapping with a wrong outer polygon.  I'm using QGIS.

Comment: What snapping options have you tried? If snapping is properly set, you shouldn't have any overlap issue (assuming your polygons are all in the same layer).

Comment: I've tried basically all the snapping options i can find.  I messed with allowing intersections and not allowing them, map units and pixels, etc.  The outer polygons (1 and 2) are a different layer than the inner polygons (a and b).  I need to make it so that none of the inner polygons can overlap with an outer polygon other than the one that covers it.

Comment: Ok. First of all you should use pixels and not map units. Even with polygons in different layers, snapping should work ([how to snap two line vertex in two different layers used in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85288/64955)). If this still doesn't work, maybe check if your layers have the same CRS.

Comment: They're definitely snapping together, but still overlapping.  The layers are the same CRS -- the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution that's working at least so far.  I'm creating two vertices on the shared boundary of the outer polygons and then snapping the inner polygons to that.

Comment: That's the correct way. Without real vertices at snapping points they must be computed on-the-fly for the overlap analysis and that is sensible to rounding errors.