# Move node feature and snap to node of other layer

Tags: qgis, snapping, nodes

This seems like I'm missing something obvious - I have a layer with node features that I need to update the position of by referencing another node layer.  Should be a simple move and snap-to operation, but there's no snap settings for nodes??? Just vertex and segment?  Is there something that I'm missing?  I was able to do a few with the QAD plugin, but that's been crashing on me and I've got hundreds more to do.

[image: error message]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are viewing?

Comment: added a screenshot to the original question

Comment: is not working for you the native snapping tool ? if you are using a point layer it should be enough to enable the vertex mode and setting the correct tolerance, then you can move the nodes with the node tool.

Comment: yes remove the QAD plugin to start with and apply this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85273/how-to-snap-two-line-vertex-in-two-different-layers-used-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks - it's been working since I removed the QAD plugin.